# jquery get image width in an ajax callback

Tags: jquery

How to get image size in an ajax callback? it returns value `0`.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "result.php", 
        dataType: "html",
        type: 'POST', 
        data: "search=robot", 
            success: function(images){ 
                $("#result").html(images);
                var width = $('#images').width();
                alert(width);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<a id="click">click</a>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

`result.php`

```
<img src="http://gandt.blogs.brynmawr.edu/files/2009/01/<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?>.jpg" id="images" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Success should look like this:

```
  success: function(images){ 
        $("#result").html(images);
        var width = $('#result img').width();
        alert(width);
    }
```

You need to get the image element from the result div. There is no element with the id of #images